# C++ get property from hash table using chaining

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, hashtable

I am implementing a hash table to help store and retrieve properties for an application. At the moment, it's mostly working, except if I try to retrieve a value that doesn't exist.  My code should return an empty string, instead it crashes. Here is the relevant code. The array is dynamically allocated.

```
struct Property {
    Property* next;
    std::string key;
    std::string value;

    Property() {
        key = "";
        value = "";
        next=NULL;
    }
};

Property* properties;
int propSize;

std::string Properties::getProperty(std::string key) {

    Property *ptr = &properties[hashcode(key)%propSize];
    if (properties[hashcode(key)%propSize].key == "") {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        while((ptr->key != key) && (ptr->next != NULL))
            ptr = ptr->next;

        if (ptr->key != key)
            return "";
        else
            return ptr->value;
    }

}
```

Comment: -1: Have you tried to debug this? What did you discover?

Comment: C++ already ships with a professionally designed hash table in `<unordered_map>` (or `<tr1/unordered_map>`, or `<boost/unordered_map.hpp>`, or `<ext/hash_map>`). Why roll your own, badly, if the aim isn't to learn how to write a hash table?

Comment: I tried to debug it and got nothing. The entire thing just stopped at the while loop.

1. I didn't know about unordered_map
2. I need to be able to go through and save all entries in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the several standard hash table implementations, like `unordered_map`.  You mentioned that you "need to be able to go through and save all entries in the map"; it is trivial to iterate over the map and do whatever you want with the elements, for example using `std::copy()`.

Comment: At the moment, none of the implementations of unordered_map are working. Following [link](http://cpptutorials.freeforums.org/tr1-unordered-map-t621.html), I received the error "‘tr1’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type." With boost's version, I got an error with code in the header.